# Can we skip EOF when reading input?

Tags: java, input, stream, java.util.scanner, eof

After I catch eof, if I try to read information from input again, I no longer get new information. Is there any way I can resume reading the data?

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
while (s.hasNextInt()) {
    A[i] = s.nextInt();
    i++;
}
```

But in applications, when I press ctrl D(EOF in Windows), it does not stop working, for example, in Intellij idea, which is also written in java.

Or a terminal to which I can send EOF, and it will continue to receive information.
As a result, how can I process the eof from the user so that my application continues to work?

Comment: Not sure about the context of your question. EOF is "end of file", and sometimes associated with a character. You can always create a new Scanner to read whatever new data com in from System.in.

Comment: but if the input was closed (indicated by EOF,) a new Scanner will not help - the *'user'* closed the input, the system will not read the input any more, there is nothing else to be read

Comment: The EOF is not sent from the scanner, it originates from System.in. That's why creating a new scanner on the same input does not help.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it embodies a contradiction in terms.

Answer (score 2):

If a stream indicates EOF it means you consumed it all. There is nothing else to be read. If the stream implementation allows, you might 'rewind' the stream and read the same bytes again. Otherwise just close it.

It's similar to having eating all the bread. After that there is no more bread to eat. Move on, find something else to eat.

Comment: Please don't expand on rewinding in the context of your metaphor.

Comment: But in applications, when I press ctrl D(EOF in Windows), it does not stop working, for example, in Intellij idea, which is also written in java

Comment: @skver You are referring to the EOT character which is a byte that can be read as any other byte and then is subject to interpretation. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#End_of_file/stream

Comment: Then how can I process the EOT so that the scanner continues to read?

Comment: Since you are using nextInt() the scanner cannot get over other bytes. You might use nextByte() though.

Comment: What changes from the type of data I'm reading? Can you show the code where EOT does not stop reading data?

Comment: There seems to be a misunderstanding; `nextByte()` does not read a `byte` from the `InputStream` but attempts to read a decimal number similar to `nextInt()`, just allowing a smaller value range and returning it as `byte`. What you actually want to do, is something like `while(i < A.length && s.hasNext()) { if(s.hasNextInt()) { A[i] = s.nextInt(); i++; } else { System.err.println(s.next() + " is not an int"); } }
  if(i < A.length) { System.err.println("not enough int numbers received"); }` reading everything not an int (including control characters) via `next()`, dropping it after reporting.